# lmer longitudinal analyses in R for variance within subjects and between timepoints

Tags: r, lme4, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I have the following longitudinal (3 `Timepoints`) data set:

```
# A tibble: 504 x 6
      ID   Age Age_group Sex    Timepoint  outcome
   <int> <int> <fct>     <chr>  <chr>        <dbl>
 1 33714    15 Young     Male   bl        0.00103 
 2 35377    15 Young     Female bl        0.00106 
 3 38623    45 Older     Female bl        0.00103 
 4 38806    66 Older     Female bl        0.00114 
 5 39593    69 Older     Female bl        0.00113 
 6 39820    60 Older     Female bl        0.00113 
 7 39951    46 Older     Male   bl        0.000986
 8 40286    68 Older     Female bl        0.00107 
 9 40556     9 Young     Male   bl        0.00114 
10 40798    11 Young     Male   bl        0.00111 
# ... with 494 more rows
```

data:

```
39820L, 39951L, 40286L, 40556L, 40798L, 40800L, 40815L, 43762L, 
50848L, 52183L, 52461L, 52577L, 53320L, 53873L, 54153L, 54206L, 
54581L, 55122L, 55267L, 55462L, 55612L, 55920L, 56022L, 56307L, 
56420L, 56679L, 57405L, 57445L, 57480L, 57725L, 57809L, 58004L, 
58215L, 58229L, 58503L, 59326L, 59327L, 59344L, 59361L, 59865L, 
60099L, 60100L, 60280L, 60384L, 60429L, 60493L, 60503L, 60575L, 
60603L, 60664L, 60846L, 61415L, 61656L, 61749L, 61883L, 62081L, 
62210L, 62285L, 62937L, 62983L, 63327L, 63329L, 64081L, 64328L, 
64418L, 64507L, 64596L, 65178L, 65250L, 65302L, 65478L, 65480L, 
65487L, 65572L, 65802L, 65935L, 65974L, 65975L, 65978L, 65991L, 
65995L, 66013L, 66154L, 66237L, 66245L, 66389L, 66396L, 66460L, 
66572L, 66589L, 67174L, 73230L, 73525L, 73539L, 73677L, 73942L, 
73953L, 74034L, 74113L, 74114L, 74427L, 74439L, 74607L, 74641L, 
74657L, 74794L, 74800L, 74836L, 74942L, 74952L, 74962L, 74969L, 
74977L, 74985L, 74989L, 75220L, 75229L, 75407L, 75653L, 75732L, 
75735L, 75757L, 75895L, 75898L, 76381L, 76559L, 76574L, 76594L, 
76595L, 76746L, 76751L, 76755L, 76759L, 76775L, 77088L, 77091L, 
77099L, 77134L, 77188L, 77203L, 77252L, 77304L, 77413L, 77453L, 
77528L, 77556L, 77585L, 77668L, 78262L, 79724L, 79730L, 79850L, 
79977L, 80052L, 80819L, 80901L, 80932L, 81064L, 81065L, 81071L, 
81098L, 81142L, 81175L, 33714L, 35377L, 38623L, 38806L, 39593L, 
39820L, 39951L, 40286L, 40556L, 40798L, 40800L, 40815L, 43762L, 
50848L, 52183L, 52461L, 52577L, 53320L, 53873L, 54153L, 54206L, 
54581L, 55122L, 55267L, 55462L, 55612L, 55920L, 56022L, 56307L, 
56420L, 56679L, 57405L, 57445L, 57480L, 57725L, 57809L, 58004L, 
58215L, 58229L, 58503L, 59326L, 59327L, 59344L, 59361L, 59865L, 
60099L, 60100L, 60280L, 60384L, 60429L, 60493L, 60503L, 60575L, 
60603L, 60664L, 60846L, 61415L, 61656L, 61749L, 61883L, 62081L, 
62210L, 62285L, 62937L, 62983L, 63327L, 63329L, 64081L, 64328L, 
64418L, 64507L, 64596L, 65178L, 65250L, 65302L, 65478L, 65480L, 
65487L, 65572L, 65802L, 65935L, 65974L, 65975L, 65978L, 65991L, 
65995L, 66013L, 66154L, 66237L, 66245L, 66389L, 66396L, 66460L, 
66572L, 66589L, 67174L, 73230L, 73525L, 73539L, 73677L, 73942L, 
73953L, 74034L, 74113L, 74114L, 74427L, 74439L, 74607L, 74641L, 
74657L, 74794L, 74800L, 74836L, 74942L, 74952L, 74962L, 74969L, 
74977L, 74985L, 74989L, 75220L, 75229L, 75407L, 75653L, 75732L, 
75735L, 75757L, 75895L, 75898L, 76381L, 76559L, 76574L, 76594L, 
76595L, 76746L, 76751L, 76755L, 76759L, 76775L, 77088L, 77091L, 
77099L, 77134L, 77188L, 77203L, 77252L, 77304L, 77413L, 77453L, 
77528L, 77556L, 77585L, 77668L, 78262L, 79724L, 79730L, 79850L, 
79977L, 80052L, 80819L, 80901L, 80932L, 81064L, 81065L, 81071L, 
81098L, 81142L, 81175L, 33714L, 35377L, 38623L, 38806L, 39593L, 
39820L, 39951L, 40286L, 40556L, 40798L, 40800L, 40815L, 43762L, 
50848L, 52183L, 52461L, 52577L, 53320L, 53873L, 54153L, 54206L, 
54581L, 55122L, 55267L, 55462L, 55612L, 55920L, 56022L, 56307L, 
56420L, 56679L, 57405L, 57445L, 57480L, 57725L, 57809L, 58004L, 
58215L, 58229L, 58503L, 59326L, 59327L, 59344L, 59361L, 59865L, 
60099L, 60100L, 60280L, 60384L, 60429L, 60493L, 60503L, 60575L, 
60603L, 60664L, 60846L, 61415L, 61656L, 61749L, 61883L, 62081L, 
62210L, 62285L, 62937L, 62983L, 63327L, 63329L, 64081L, 64328L, 
64418L, 64507L, 64596L, 65178L, 65250L, 65302L, 65478L, 65480L, 
65487L, 65572L, 65802L, 65935L, 65974L, 65975L, 65978L, 65991L, 
65995L, 66013L, 66154L, 66237L, 66245L, 66389L, 66396L, 66460L, 
66572L, 66589L, 67174L, 73230L, 73525L, 73539L, 73677L, 73942L, 
73953L, 74034L, 74113L, 74114L, 74427L, 74439L, 74607L, 74641L, 
74657L, 74794L, 74800L, 74836L, 74942L, 74952L, 74962L, 74969L, 
74977L, 74985L, 74989L, 75220L, 75229L, 75407L, 75653L, 75732L, 
75735L, 75757L, 75895L, 75898L, 76381L, 76559L, 76574L, 76594L, 
76595L, 76746L, 76751L, 76755L, 76759L, 76775L, 77088L, 77091L, 
77099L, 77134L, 77188L, 77203L, 77252L, 77304L, 77413L, 77453L, 
77528L, 77556L, 77585L, 77668L, 78262L, 79724L, 79730L, 79850L, 
79977L, 80052L, 80819L, 80901L, 80932L, 81064L, 81065L, 81071L, 
81098L, 81142L, 81175L), Age = c(15L, 15L, 45L, 66L, 69L, 60L, 
46L, 68L, 9L, 11L, 16L, 9L, 56L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 53L, 8L, 6L, 
63L, 14L, 10L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 58L, 
10L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 15L, 43L, 8L, 11L, 44L, 70L, 14L, 12L, 10L, 
16L, 12L, 10L, 6L, 13L, 67L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 10L, 66L, 13L, 14L, 
12L, 45L, 52L, 64L, 17L, 9L, 12L, 44L, 69L, 11L, 10L, 12L, 10L, 
10L, 70L, 54L, 45L, 43L, 54L, 14L, 42L, 44L, 16L, 15L, 43L, 45L, 
50L, 53L, 53L, 49L, 69L, 14L, 65L, 14L, 13L, 67L, 59L, 52L, 54L, 
44L, 62L, 69L, 10L, 63L, 57L, 12L, 62L, 9L, 53L, 54L, 66L, 49L, 
63L, 51L, 9L, 45L, 49L, 49L, 61L, 62L, 57L, 67L, 65L, 45L, 16L, 
55L, 64L, 67L, 56L, 52L, 63L, 10L, 62L, 14L, 66L, 68L, 15L, 13L, 
43L, 47L, 55L, 69L, 67L, 52L, 15L, 64L, 55L, 44L, 13L, 48L, 71L, 
64L, 13L, 50L, 61L, 70L, 57L, 51L, 46L, 57L, 69L, 46L, 8L, 11L, 
46L, 71L, 38L, 56L, 16L, 16L, 46L, 67L, 70L, 61L, 47L, 69L, 11L, 
13L, 18L, 10L, 57L, 18L, 18L, 15L, 54L, 10L, 8L, 64L, 15L, 12L, 
16L, 14L, 16L, 9L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 59L, 12L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 8L, 16L, 44L, 9L, 13L, 45L, 71L, 16L, 13L, 12L, 18L, 
13L, 11L, 8L, 14L, 68L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 11L, 67L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 
46L, 53L, 65L, 18L, 11L, 14L, 46L, 70L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 11L, 
71L, 55L, 46L, 44L, 55L, 15L, 43L, 45L, 17L, 16L, 44L, 46L, 51L, 
55L, 54L, 50L, 70L, 15L, 66L, 15L, 14L, 68L, 60L, 53L, 55L, 46L, 
63L, 70L, 11L, 64L, 58L, 13L, 63L, 10L, 54L, 55L, 67L, 50L, 64L, 
52L, 11L, 46L, 50L, 50L, 62L, 63L, 58L, 68L, 66L, 46L, 18L, 56L, 
65L, 68L, 57L, 53L, 64L, 11L, 63L, 15L, 67L, 69L, 16L, 14L, 44L, 
48L, 56L, 70L, 68L, 53L, 17L, 65L, 56L, 45L, 14L, 49L, 73L, 65L, 
14L, 50L, 62L, 71L, 58L, 52L, 47L, 58L, 70L, 47L, 9L, 12L, 47L, 
72L, 39L, 57L, 18L, 18L, 47L, 68L, 71L, 62L, 48L, 70L, 12L, 14L, 
19L, 11L, 58L, 19L, 19L, 16L, 55L, 11L, 9L, 65L, 17L, 13L, 18L, 
16L, 18L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 60L, 13L, 9L, 11L, 
10L, 9L, 17L, 45L, 11L, 14L, 46L, 72L, 17L, 14L, 13L, 19L, 15L, 
12L, 9L, 15L, 69L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 12L, 68L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 47L, 
54L, 66L, 20L, 12L, 15L, 47L, 71L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 12L, 12L, 72L, 
56L, 47L, 45L, 56L, 16L, 44L, 46L, 19L, 18L, 44L, 47L, 52L, 56L, 
55L, 51L, 71L, 16L, 67L, 16L, 15L, 69L, 60L, 54L, 56L, 46L, 64L, 
71L, 12L, 65L, 59L, 14L, 64L, 11L, 55L, 57L, 68L, 51L, 65L, 53L, 
11L, 47L, 51L, 51L, 63L, 64L, 59L, 69L, 67L, 48L, 19L, 57L, 66L, 
69L, 59L, 54L, 65L, 12L, 64L, 16L, 68L, 70L, 17L, 15L, 45L, 48L, 
57L, 71L, 69L, 54L, 18L, 66L, 57L, 50L, 15L, 50L, 74L, 66L, 15L, 
51L, 63L, 72L, 59L, 53L, 48L, 59L, 71L, 48L, 10L, 13L, 48L, 73L, 
40L, 58L), Age_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Young", "Older"), class = "factor"), Sex = c("Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", 
"Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female"), Timepoint = c("bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", "bl", 
"bl", "bl", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", "flu1", 
"flu1", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", "flu2", 
"flu2"), outcome = c(0.0010333, 0.00105981, 0.00103209, 0.001136335, 
0.001130695, 0.00113139, 0.000986063, 0.0010712, 0.00113736, 
0.001108715, 0.00104864, 0.00110772, 0.00110197, 0.00109096, 
0.00109855, 0.00104169, 0.001090875, 0.00112465, 0.001096525, 
0.001030151, 0.000985059, 0.001098955, 0.001069465, 0.00105376, 
0.00106878, 0.00110388, 0.00108702, 0.001162835, 0.001070955, 
0.0010971, 0.00111695, 0.001060525, 0.001035065, 0.00108797, 
0.00103262, 0.001117605, 0.001061707, 0.001156365, 0.00104431, 
0.001056565, 0.00109114, 0.001053765, 0.001064622, 0.001114025, 
0.001045395, 0.00106441, 0.00108481, 0.0011145, 0.001095115, 
0.001099075, 0.001057, 0.001096125, 0.001087175, 0.00109696, 
0.001064795, 0.00108024, 0.00102137, 0.001087645, 0.001103185, 
0.00111948, 0.001110965, 0.0010694, 0.001089425, 0.001129075, 
0.00103784, 0.00104419, 0.00101302, 0.00110335, 0.00111867, 0.00108785, 
0.001098765, 0.001052415, 0.0010976, 0.001064385, 0.00108407, 
0.001076165, 0.00112799, 0.00106542, 0.00105824, 0.001129705, 
0.001051684, 0.001073525, 0.001076575, 0.001049785, 0.00102377, 
0.0011, 0.001039055, 0.00105945, 0.001083505, 0.0010723, 0.001123395, 
0.00103181, 0.00110417, 0.001078155, 0.001129015, 0.00114891, 
0.001115405, 0.00110057, 0.001054205, 0.00105165, 0.001095601, 
0.001112195, 0.001024814, 0.001061645, 0.001081505, 0.00109171, 
0.00112992, 0.001007862, 0.001069345, 0.00108842, 0.001066665, 
0.00106081, 0.001065165, 0.00108621, 0.001099885, 0.00103779, 
0.00103329, 0.00107046, 0.001094945, 0.001063225, 0.001077665, 
0.0011242, 0.001161425, 0.001092915, 0.00109162, 0.001120835, 
0.001060845, 0.001072238, 0.00109486, 0.00111587, 0.001166475, 
0.001060665, 0.00107877, 0.00106572, 0.00103524, 0.001112615, 
0.00106803, 0.00113409, 0.000992363, 0.001057025, 0.001055855, 
0.001165165, 0.001046216, 0.001015101, 0.001052505, 0.001094015, 
0.00104152, 0.00104361, 0.001138575, 0.001056924, 0.0011807, 
0.001090905, 0.00108723, 0.00106178, 0.00113283, 0.001154635, 
0.00110195, 0.001115265, 0.001102255, 0.00106396, 0.001073585, 
0.001047345, 0.001046765, 0.001090765, 0.001022798, 0.001187635, 
0.001033095, 0.00112301, 0.001060205, 0.0010143, 0.00102627, 
0.00110609, 0.001158665, 0.00112353, 0.00097819, 0.001078495, 
0.001106365, 0.00113328, 0.001045545, 0.001081185, 0.00109504, 
0.001102495, 0.00108775, 0.001055425, 0.001056945, 0.001130705, 
0.00115777, 0.001034427, 0.00105974, 0.001089395, 0.001069105, 
0.001054605, 0.00107229, 0.001128765, 0.001111455, 0.001111155, 
0.001095955, 0.001108905, 0.001077275, 0.00104525, 0.00105191, 
0.00111458, 0.001110655, 0.001114555, 0.00110557, 0.001167755, 
0.0010552, 0.001014149, 0.00110002, 0.00104991, 0.001018892, 
0.00112666, 0.001069695, 0.001101185, 0.001066815, 0.00109388, 
0.001079455, 0.001097655, 0.001106855, 0.00108804, 0.001024891, 
0.001102495, 0.001077445, 0.00104224, 0.001064015, 0.001071736, 
0.00110557, 0.00112483, 0.001093865, 0.001075945, 0.001031211, 
0.001122935, 0.00105965, 0.001048305, 0.0010719, 0.00107988, 
0.001161715, 0.001098505, 0.001073105, 0.001049325, 0.001097175, 
0.00111584, 0.00112603, 0.00107674, 0.001147125, 0.00104971, 
0.00108423, 0.001122035, 0.00103364, 0.001071835, 0.001036422, 
0.001016249, 0.00101976, 0.00107818, 0.001067145, 0.001062425, 
0.00110346, 0.00108456, 0.00113592, 0.001015195, 0.001110565, 
0.00110143, 0.001121325, 0.00110386, 0.00112389, 0.001091155, 
0.00105652, 0.001030636, 0.001106515, 0.00109062, 0.001047755, 
0.001030305, 0.00108161, 0.001063235, 0.00112294, 0.001079355, 
0.001052327, 0.00107416, 0.001091, 0.001057725, 0.00107489, 0.0010597, 
0.001086495, 0.001047792, 0.000995212, 0.001092055, 0.00106338, 
0.001078475, 0.00110247, 0.00111765, 0.00113914, 0.001073185, 
0.001074005, 0.001091145, 0.001040767, 0.00106448, 0.00105502, 
0.00108874, 0.00117407, 0.00109106, 0.001044455, 0.00103907, 
0.00104921, 0.001136435, 0.0010907, 0.001101685, 0.001009874, 
0.00106717, 0.001055338, 0.001157375, 0.001061175, 0.000983892, 
0.001017475, 0.001094945, 0.001018795, 0.00107304, 0.00113138, 
0.0010772, 0.00114321, 0.00111869, 0.001086615, 0.0010709, 0.00116752, 
0.001175765, 0.001113535, 0.001123455, 0.001081295, 0.001084425, 
0.00107189, 0.001030513, 0.001076375, 0.001088265, 0.001043751, 
0.001157355, 0.001039899, 0.00116496, 0.00106309, 0.00106822, 
0.001076605, 0.001113025, 0.00115085, 0.00115274, 0.001005614, 
0.00111759, 0.001052205, 0.001106125, 0.001060125, 0.00106945, 
0.00107761, 0.001092695, 0.00107696, 0.001063425, 0.00111791, 
0.001116725, 0.00105891, 0.001033532, 0.001054205, 0.00109295, 
0.00109387, 0.00101807, 0.001066195, 0.001120295, 0.001111565, 
0.001088595, 0.00102183, 0.0010934, 0.00111935, 0.00105371, 0.001038104, 
0.00108314, 0.0011006, 0.001079585, 0.001127775, 0.001140825, 
0.00106203, 0.001059563, 0.001118035, 0.00103535, 0.001027819, 
0.001120055, 0.00099512, 0.001078955, 0.00108867, 0.0010789, 
0.001030445, 0.00106243, 0.001028545, 0.00108679, 0.00108158, 
0.00105624, 0.001110145, 0.00107318, 0.00106523, 0.001099325, 
0.001103515, 0.00112404, 0.001064455, 0.001086375, 0.001109065, 
0.001077765, 0.001040425, 0.001059305, 0.00106362, 0.00109264, 
0.00116222, 0.001079395, 0.00107183, 0.0010652, 0.00106983, 0.00111722, 
0.00112626, 0.001091765, 0.00113837, 0.00104618, 0.00109727, 
0.00114111, 0.001055565, 0.001115175, 0.001059649, 0.001029902, 
0.000986792, 0.00107968, 0.00106097, 0.001067105, 0.001083625, 
0.00109082, 0.00114355, 0.001062825, 0.001099115, 0.001102155, 
0.001122135, 0.001125253, 0.001131355, 0.001104175, 0.001104315, 
0.00103858, 0.001072123, 0.00109497, 0.00103623, 0.00107783, 
0.00107379, 0.00108648, 0.00114186, 0.001081035, 0.00110761, 
0.001102845, 0.001090495, 0.00105551, 0.00108908, 0.001082845, 
0.001110075, 0.0010599, 0.001042808, 0.00108644, 0.00106482, 
0.00111119, 0.001077005, 0.001183845, 0.001134605, 0.00107317, 
0.001039397, 0.00112268, 0.00108716, 0.00108437, 0.0010827, 0.00111043, 
0.001177305, 0.001057715, 0.00110218, 0.0010338, 0.00103996, 
0.00111301, 0.001071455, 0.001072065, 0.00100762, 0.00106678, 
0.001030939, 0.001161045, 0.001080915, 0.001053775, 0.001032233, 
0.001072078, 0.00103878, 0.00112049, 0.00111996, 0.001085025, 
0.001165745, 0.00114263, 0.00106407, 0.00109784, 0.001187105, 
0.001194925, 0.001139195, 0.0011009, 0.00110112, 0.00107563, 
0.001055985, 0.00100656, 0.0010693, 0.001104395, 0.001022506, 
0.00114974, 0.00105716, 0.00113243)), row.names = c(NA, -504L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

`outcome` is a physiological measure that was sampled per subject (`ID`) at `timepoint-bl` (1), `timepoint-flu1` (2) and `timepoint-flu2` (3). Each subject `age`, `age_group` and `sex` are recorded as well. `Age` is a predictor of `outcome` and `sex` is used as an interaction variable.

Aims:

1. I am trying to estimate if there is a significant difference in slope of the `outcome` variable *between* `Young` and `Older` adults across the 3 `Timepoints`.
2. I am trying to estimate the *individual* (`ID`) variance of `outcome` between `timepoints` *and* `age_group`.

Is this the correct way to model for my aims? The plot doesn't look accurate to me. I am new to linear mixed models so any advice is appreciated.

```
#mixed
DF_mixed <- lmer(outcome ~ Age* Sex + (1 + Age| Age_group:Timepoint) + (1|ID), data = DF) 
# identify age*sex interactions to predict outcome value between timepoints, nested in age_group that have random slope and intercepts

#plot
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Age, y = outcome, color = Timepoint)) +
      geom_point(alpha = 0.7) +
      theme_classic() +
      geom_line(data = cbind(DF, pred = predict(DF_mixed)), aes(y = pred), size = 1)   # adding predicted line from mixed model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below, I walk through suggestions for (1) preparing your data, (2) specifying the model, and (3) examining model results.

In addition to `tidyverse` packages and `lme4`, I'll use `broom.mixed::glance()` and `tidy()` to inspect model parameters, and `ggeffects::ggpredict()` to generate model predictions for plotting.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
library(broom.mixed)
library(ggeffects)
```

#### Data Prep & Variable Selection

`Timepoint` is a character, and will be treated as as an unordered category in the model, which likely isn't what you want. It's often better to use the actual time elapsed since baseline rather than a generic "timepoint," especially if distance between timepoints is variable. For this answer, I computed an alternate `Timepoint_yrs` based on each subject's change in age from baseline; but if you have a more precise record of time, you may want to use that instead.

Also, `outcome` consists of a small range of values, on the order of 1e-4 - 1e-3; this can cause lmer to misbehave, so I scaled this.

```r
DF <- DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Timepoint_yrs = Age - min(Age)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(outcome_scaled = as.numeric(scale(outcome)))
```

Including both `Age` and `Age_group` in the model will cause issues with multicollinearity, as one is a function of the other. Given the extreme bimodal distribution of `Age`, I just used `Age_group`. And as above, change in age is now accounted for by `Timepoint_yrs`.

#### Model Specification

*"I am trying to estimate if there is a significant difference in slope of the outcome variable between `Young` and `Older` adults across the 3 `Timepoints`"* -- i.e., an `Age_group` by `Timepoint_yrs` interaction. You also wrote that *"`sex` is used as an interaction variable."* So putting this together, you're looking at a 3-way `Age_group` by `Sex` by `Timepoint_yrs` interaction. Because `Age_group` and `Sex` only vary between subjects, we'll specify this at the level of fixed effects:

```r
outcome_scaled ~ Age_group * Sex * Timepoint_yrs
```

Because you have multiple measurements per person (`ID`), we'll include random intercepts for `ID`:

```r
outcome_scaled ~ Age_group * Sex * Timepoint_yrs + (1 | ID)
```

We can also allow the slope of `Timepoint_yrs` to vary within individuals. From your post, I don't see a strong theoretical reason for whether or not to include random slopes -- so we'll do both and see which model fits best.

```r
# model 1 - random intercepts
rnd_intercept <- lmer(outcome_scaled ~ Age_group * Sex * Timepoint_yrs + (1 | ID), data = DF) 

# model 2 - random intercepts and slopes
rnd_int_slope <- lmer(outcome_scaled ~ Age_group * Sex * Timepoint_yrs + (Timepoint_yrs | ID), data = DF)
```

#### Model Results

```r
glance(rnd_intercept)
# # A tibble: 1 x 6
# sigma logLik   AIC   BIC REMLcrit df.residual
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
# 1 0.510  -575. 1170. 1212.    1150.         494

glance(rnd_int_slopes)
# A tibble: 1 x 6
#   sigma logLik   AIC   BIC REMLcrit df.residual
#   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int>
# 1 0.487  -575. 1173. 1224.    1149.         492
```

Looking at AIC and BIC, the random intercepts model seems a better / more parsimonious fit; absent any theoretical reason to prefer the random slopes model, we'll stick with that one.

```r
tidy(rnd_intercept, conf.int = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 10 x 8
#    effect   group    term               estimate std.error statistic conf.low conf.high
#    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>                 <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#  1 fixed    NA       (Intercept)         -0.123     0.122    -1.01    -0.361     0.116 
#  2 fixed    NA       Age_groupYoung      -0.0142    0.221    -0.0643  -0.448     0.419 
#  3 fixed    NA       SexMale              0.248     0.214     1.16    -0.171     0.667 
#  4 fixed    NA       Timepoint_yrs        0.131     0.0407    3.21     0.0509    0.210 
#  5 fixed    NA       Age_groupYoung:Se~  -0.0704    0.317    -0.222   -0.692     0.551 
#  6 fixed    NA       Age_groupYoung:Ti~  -0.152     0.0654   -2.32    -0.280    -0.0234
#  7 fixed    NA       SexMale:Timepoint~  -0.0547    0.0771   -0.709   -0.206     0.0964
#  8 fixed    NA       Age_groupYoung:Se~   0.0192    0.101     0.190   -0.178     0.217 
#  9 ran_pars ID       sd__(Intercept)      0.862    NA        NA       NA        NA     
# 10 ran_pars Residual sd__Observation      0.510    NA        NA       NA        NA
```

Finally, we can plot predicted values from the model. Your original code predicted a datapoint for every row in your original data, then basically traced a line between each of these, which as you noted isn't very informative. Instead, we want to base the plot on just one predicted outcome value (+/- error) for each unique combination of your predictors. `ggeffects::ggpredict()` is a nice shortcut for this; `emmeans::emmeans()` would be another option.

```r
plot_data <- ggpredict(rnd_intercept, terms = c("Timepoint_yrs", "Age_group", "Sex"))
# col names: x = Timepoint_yrs, group = Age_group, facet = Sex, predicted = observed_scaled

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x, predicted)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = group)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high, fill = group), alpha = .1) +
  facet_wrap(vars(facet)) +
  labs(x = "Years Since Baseline", y = "Outcome\n(scaled, model-predicted)") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: a faceted plot showing predicted values by age, sex, and timepoint with 95% confidence bands. predicted values generally increase over time for "Older" group and decrease over time for "Young" group, though with overlapping 95% confidence bands. there are no obvious differences by sex.]

Based on your model coefficients, you may also want to look at just `Age_group` across `Timepoint_yrs`, as well as the main effect of `Timepoint_yrs` collapsed across other variables. You can do this by changing the `terms` argument to `ggpredict()` and modifying the `ggplot` spec accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I think the random slope is necessary given that the data is biological and `ID` is a different person, each with their own unique anatomy. With this model, is it possible to identify *individual* change over time? Similar to a structural equation modeling of latent change score, if you're familiar with that.

Comment: @CanyonView You’re welcome! Yes, you can extract individual slopes for time. Here are a couple relevant CV threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/535279/140918, 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122018/140918. I’ll try to update my answer with an example when I have a chance, but may not be til the weekend.